# Should I always override equals, hashcode and toString methods?

Tags: java, class, comparison, equals, hashcode

I have rather simple question: According to best programming practices, when I create a new model class should I always override equals, hashcode and toString methods? Even I do not intend to compare objects of specific class?

Comment: If you don't intend to compare them **and** you don't intend to store them in data structures whose sorting relies on `compareTo` or whose uniqueness of contents relies on `hashCode` and `equals`, then you won't have to...

Comment: Just because you don't intend to compare them now, doesn't mean you never will. or you may, in the future, use something in the lines of myList.contains(testObject);

Comment: Ideally yes but not in practice then, if you can (the object is "well defined", the uniqueness is "well defined", equality, ...) it's better to define them, otherwise let the default implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of these methods has its own significance. `equals` and `hashCode` methods are used for comparison and hashing and `toString` mainly for logging purposes. 
If you don't want any of these functionalities, you are not required to implement them.

Answer (score 2):

Another best practice is to not implement code that is never used. So implement those methods mostly on demand. One reason to implement those methods without using them right away would be to assure a specific implementation or behaviour which one other developer maybe could not be aware of when he implements it on demand. So for your question: No, not always.

Answer (score 1):

Even though above answers are correct, I would like to add on why these methods are actually overridden.
If your model class will be used as a key of a **Map** or a **Tree**, or in a **Set**, its best practice to override **equals** and **hashCode** method (as it will be needed for comparing 2 model class objects).

**toString** you will need to override, if you want you want to display your model class data in a efficient way. 
Suppose if you have a model class, **Dummy**, having 2 fields, **field1** and **field2**.

```
// Without overriding toString
System.out.println("field1: " + dummyObj.field1 + " field2"+dummyObj.field2);

// With overriding toString
System.out.println(dummyObj);

// Your overridden toString
public String toString(){
  return "field1: " + this.field1 + " field2"+this.field2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per `my own perspective`

You should not override always `hashcode` and `equal` but you should override `toString`

```
why toString?
```

say you have a `class` with more than 10 properties and you are debugging an object that it is populated or not,

I would prefer to not check through getter instead print out an object will reduce my time

```
hashcode and equal?
```

these two methods come into the picture whenever we use hash-based collection like:

```
(1) hashSet, (2) hashTable, (3) hashMap and few more
```

if you are not intended to use collection and comparing of an object! 
then you just have useless code which creates ambiguity

Comment: you think equals is only used if you use hashSet, hashTable and/or hashMap? seriously?

Comment: No, it could be used for an override behavior of the `Object` class toString method that's why I mentioned `comparing of an object!`

Comment: you think equals can be used "for an override behavior of the Object class toString method" ?

Comment: Ohh well caught :) it's `equals` in my comment instead `toString`

Answer (score 0):

The decision should be based on

- consistency (guide lines, and code checkers)
- quality
- code style
- effort (writing, reading & understanding implications)

I myself am rather lax, feeling that not every class needs that much of attention (for a possible future use).

Though guide lines should be followed stoically. Code checkers almost never be ignored.

As IDEs and even libraries provide easily created boiler code for generating the methods, the effort is low, but the code style can become unnecesarily bloated. Especially for inner classes.

And of course "callback" event handling classes do not need them.